# Pairwise distance between objects (Xarray)

Tags: scipy, distance, python-xarray

I have 3 `cars` travelling in `space` (x,y)  at 10 `time` steps.

For each time step I want to calculate the pairwise Euclidean distance between cars.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
import xarray as xr

data = np.random.rand(3,2,10)

times = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=10)
space = ['x','y']
cars = ['a','b','c']

foo = xr.DataArray(data, coords=[cars,space,times], dims = ['cars','space','time'])
```

The for loop iteration below works fine, each input is 3*2 array , and `pdist` is happily calculating a condensed distance matrix for all the pairwise distances between cars

```
    for label,group in foo.groupby('time'):
        print(group.shape, type(group), pdist(group) )

(3, 2) <class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'> [0.45389929 0.96104589 0.51489773]
(3, 2) <class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'> [0.87532985 0.49758256 0.4418555 ]
(3, 2) <class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'> [0.44036486 0.17947479 0.39842543]
(3, 2) <class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'> [0.52294711 0.26278261 0.78106623]
(3, 2) <class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'> [0.30004324 0.62807379 0.40601505]
(3, 2) <class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'> [0.48351623 0.38331324 0.30677522]
(3, 2) <class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'> [0.83682031 0.38409803 0.455275  ]
(3, 2) <class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'> [0.33614753 0.50814237 0.49033016]
(3, 2) <class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'> [0.17365559 0.33567641 0.30382769]
(3, 2) <class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'> [0.76981095 0.18099241 0.91187884]
```

but this simple call  ( which should do the identical operation as I understand it ) is failing.

```
foo.groupby('time').apply(pdist)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dims'
```

It seems to be having trouble with the return shape ?  do I need a `u_func` here ?

BTW all these calls work fine and returns as expected with a variety of shapes:

```
foo.groupby('time').apply(np.mean)
foo.groupby('time').apply(np.mean,axis=0)
foo.groupby('time').apply(np.mean,axis=1)
```

thanks in advance for any pointers...

Comment: I have a hunch `pdist` in breaking the return structure somehow...  `pdist` doesn't return an `xarray` object..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pdist changes the array size and therefore xarray can not find its coordinates.

How about the following?

```
In [12]: np.sqrt(((foo - foo.rename(cars='cars1'))**2).sum('space'))
Out[12]: 
<xarray.DataArray (cars: 3, time: 10, cars1: 3)>
array([[[0.      , 0.131342, 0.352521],
        [0.      , 0.329914, 0.859899],
        [0.      , 0.933117, 0.351842],
        [0.      , 0.802514, 0.426005],
        [0.      , 0.167081, 0.563704],
        [0.      , 0.9822  , 0.145496],
        [0.      , 0.894892, 0.457217],
        [0.      , 0.333222, 0.505805],
        [0.      , 0.377352, 0.604625],
        [0.      , 0.467771, 0.62544 ]],

       [[0.131342, 0.      , 0.243476],
        [0.329914, 0.      , 0.813076],
        [0.933117, 0.      , 0.847525],
        [0.802514, 0.      , 0.390665],
        [0.167081, 0.      , 0.562188],
        [0.9822  , 0.      , 0.957067],
        [0.894892, 0.      , 0.525863],
        [0.333222, 0.      , 0.835241],
        [0.377352, 0.      , 0.894856],
        [0.467771, 0.      , 0.594124]],

       [[0.352521, 0.243476, 0.      ],
        [0.859899, 0.813076, 0.      ],
        [0.351842, 0.847525, 0.      ],
        [0.426005, 0.390665, 0.      ],
        [0.563704, 0.562188, 0.      ],
        [0.145496, 0.957067, 0.      ],
        [0.457217, 0.525863, 0.      ],
        [0.505805, 0.835241, 0.      ],
        [0.604625, 0.894856, 0.      ],
        [0.62544 , 0.594124, 0.      ]]])
Coordinates:
  * cars     (cars) <U1 'a' 'b' 'c'
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2000-01-10
  * cars1    (cars1) <U1 'a' 'b' 'c'
```

If you like to have a similar output to `pdist`, `apply_ufunc` can be used,

```
In [21]:xr.apply_ufunc(pdist, foo, input_core_dims=[['cars', 'space']], 
    ...:               output_core_dims=[['cars_pair']], vectorize=True)
    ...:                
Out[21]: 
<xarray.DataArray (time: 10, cars_pair: 3)>
array([[0.131342, 0.352521, 0.243476],
       [0.329914, 0.859899, 0.813076],
       [0.933117, 0.351842, 0.847525],
       [0.802514, 0.426005, 0.390665],
       [0.167081, 0.563704, 0.562188],
       [0.9822  , 0.145496, 0.957067],
       [0.894892, 0.457217, 0.525863],
       [0.333222, 0.505805, 0.835241],
       [0.377352, 0.604625, 0.894856],
       [0.467771, 0.62544 , 0.594124]])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2000-01-10
Dimensions without coordinates: cars_pair
```